# The right JavaScript Inheritance for this specific case

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I'm dealing with a database table object that will contains all table info like fields name, table name, ecc.

That object have a method spawnRecord that will return a void record object that inherits from the table object.

The record object represent a single record of the db and have methods like load, update and insert. This allows to load a db record in the memory, to modify it and to update the same in the db.

Since I need to create many table objects and many record objects what is the most easy and clean way to do this?

I read the Douglas Crockford prototype approach, the classical approach, I tried to implement it but I get a lot of confusion and a code difficult to read.

Comment: On general principles, I advise embracing Javascript as Javascript and go for the *prototype approach*. --- If you show some of your code attempts, someone might help you out with getting them working.

Answer (score 0):

From what you're describing, it sounds like you need an ORM (object-relational mapping) tool for JavaScript.  Maybe something like [jazzrecord](http://www.jazzrecord.org/)  or [activejs](http://www.activejs.org/) will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery.klass](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-klass/).
It supports multiple levels of inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this John Resig's way - a tiny script does many things -

http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/

1)  multi level inheritance
2) 'instanceof' works as it should
3) call super class method from a subclass using 'super'
4) provide a constructor etc.